# Office 365 Groups vs MS Teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, microsoft-teams

Major differences between Office 365 groups, Team sites. As I referred some links which are saying both are same. Both will create the SharePoint modern site. Then why we need both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two great articles on groups, and the last one is a video of a comparison of the two features of Office 365 and more what I think you are looking for:

Office 365 Groups – What You Get and What to Use:

https://en.share-gate.com/blog/groups-for-office-365

Office 365 Groups Explained:

https://en.share-gate.com/blog/office-365-groups-explained

Office 365 Groups vs SharePoint Team Sites:

https://en.share-gate.com/blog/microsoft-modern-workplace

I hope the last one, the video helps!

Happy SharePoint-ing!

Answer (score 1):

They are both exactly the same.

MS teams is just another front from which you can create Office 365 group enabled modern team site.

You can create these sites from multiple point of contacts like SharePoint, Teams, Outlook , Admin center etc.

MS has just provided multiple fronts from which you can create these. The end-result is exactly the same i.e Office 365 group enabled Modern team site with associated baggage of Outlook mailbox, planner, Teams, Stream, OneNote etc.

The only minor difference I found was that, whenever we create it via Teams, it is by default associated to a Team. But if created via SharePoint, we need to manually associate the Office 365 group to a Team. Other than that, it provisions all the same artefacts.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Teams and Office 365 Groups both provide collaboration services for groups of people.

Teams and Groups isn’t oranges to apples but yin to yang, two halves forming the full picture; Groups is how you share your resources, and Teams is how you talk about what’s being shared.

The most notable difference between the two is the chat feature in Teams.